# Adding Angular directive using decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-directive, angular-decorator

I'm using Angular 1.4.8 with Angular UI.  What I'm trying to do is decorate the `ui-sref` directive so it will highlight a menu element (by setting the CSS class 'active') if the current `$state.name` matches the `ui-sref` state.

I test to see if the element is descendent from my nav header, and if it is, I want to add an `ngClass` attribute to the element.  For right now, I just want to make them all highlight; I can add the test for matching the state later.  The `true` will be replaced with the actual test.  Right now I just want the `active` class set

```
.config(['$provide', ($provide: angular.auto.IProvideService) => {
    return $provide.decorator('uiSrefDirective', [
        '$delegate', ($delegate) => {
            var originalUiSref = $delegate[0];
            var originalUiSrefLink = originalUiSref.link;

            originalUiSref.compile = () => (scope, element, attrs, uiSref) => {
                var topBar = $('nav.top-bar');
                if (topBar.length > 0 && $.contains(topBar[0], element[0])) {
                    element.parent().attr('ng-class', '{ active: true }');    
                }

                originalUiSrefLink.call($delegate, scope, element, attrs, uiSref);
            };

            return $delegate;
        }
    ]);
}])
```

The original DOM element:

```
<a ui-sref="requests">Requests</a>
```

After adding the decorator, this is what I see in my browser's DOM:

```
<a ui-sref="requests" ng-class="{ active: true }" href="/requests">Requests</a>
```

Great!  I can see the added attribute in the DOM, but my browser is ignoring it.  It's almost as though it's getting added *after* Angular scans the DOM for directives.  If I change the code to:

```
element.parent().addClass('active');
```

... then it works fine.  **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: what is wrong with `ui-sref-active` ? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Comment: I just didn't know about it.  Thanks!

Comment: I consider that an answer to this question.  If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amy you do not need to implement this directive as angular-ui in fact already have it, please check [`ui-sref-active`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)