# AngularJS ui-router - set menu active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use AngularJS ui-router and I have the problem that I habe a submenu which i reachable from menu1 and menu2.
Is it possible anywhere to highlight either **Menu1** or **Menu2**?

```
Menu1: ng-class="{'active': vm.state.includes('auth.Menu1') || vm.state.includes('auth.SubMenu')}"
Menu2: ng-class="{'active': vm.state.includes('auth.Menu2') || vm.state.includes('auth.SubMenu')}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Angular directive using decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686823/adding-angular-directive-using-decorator)

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215656/how-to-detect-current-state-within-directive/17225152#17225152

Comment: @SeanLarkin there are other questions not just these two

Answer (score 1):

People keep asking this question, you should use [`ui-sref-active`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) directive

Comment: Find the dup and flag as dupe! :-D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215656/how-to-detect-current-state-within-directive/17225152#17225152

Comment: I have removed ui-sref-active because I don't know how to implement it with this directive.

Comment: Your menu item is just a li/a etc tag with `ui-sref` directive and the path. Just put `ui-sref-active` on both.